# как сделать елементы в массиве в uppercase

Tags: javascript

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при поиске елементов в массиве делать их в uppercase, как это можно сделать? Я пытался делать через `arr.indexOf(department).toUpperCase()` но не работает

```
var arr = [];
var department = $(".js-new-department").val(),
$(".ct__department").each(function() {
  var nameDep = $(this).data("department-name");
  arr.push(nameDep);
});

if (arr.indexOf(department) == -1) {...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = [];
var department = $(".js-new-department").val(),
$(".ct__department").each(function() {
  var nameDep = $(this).data("department-name");
  arr.push(nameDep.toUpperCase());
});

if (arr.indexOf(department.toUpperCase()) == -1) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Или через [JQuery Map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)/[JS Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
// JQuery
var a = $.map($('a'), e => $(e).text().toUpperCase());
console.log(a);
// JS
var b = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].map(e => e.innerText.toUpperCase());
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>aaa</a>
<a>ббб</a>
<a>ввв</a>
```